# Asterisk forward a call to number A and when A hangs up, forward to B

Tags: asterisk

My use case is really simple: Asterisk is the middleman, it receives the call from outside and it forwards to A, when A hangs up, I want to forward it to B immediately. Is it sufficient to make another Dial?
Do you have any example?

```
+12345 --- Asterisk------------------ B
              |    when A hangs up call B
              |
              A
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If A is called with the Dial application, you could use the 'g' option and put the call to B after the first Dial to A.

According with the Dial  documentation:

> g - Proceed with dialplan execution at the next priority in the current extension if the destination channel hangs up

In the following example, dialing 1001 asterisk calls first SIP/A. If A hangups, asterisk calls B. It is not necessary the option 'g' in the last call. I leave it to be able of modifying the Dial in a future or in case I wanted to grow the chain. Note the last Hangup that, if there was not option 'g' it would not be strictly necessary, but even without 'g' option can be convenient (if you put timeouts and you want to play sounds if the timeout comes).

```
exten => 1001, 1, Dial(SIP/A,,gm)
same => n, Dial(SIP/B,,gm)
same => n, Hangup()
```

Comment: could you please make an example of the g usage?